# Netflix tools in NodeJS for micro services

Tags: node.js, microservices, netflix-eureka, hystrix, netflix

Is there service discovery (eureka), circuit breaker pattern (Hystrix), client side load-balancing (ribbon) and api gateway (Zuul) implementation available on NodeJS? I see nice integration of these components in Spring framework for Java but is anything such that available in NodeJS?

Netflix has provided an alternative way for non JVM languages through Prana (https://github.com/Netflix/Prana) but it is not actively supported. Is there any alternative suite of production ready components available for NodeJS? Ideally one of the benefit of micro services is each service can be developed in different language. Are there any good option available or should I implement myself?

Comment: Buzzword alphabet soup there; NGINX with [reverse proxying](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/load-balancer/) may do what you want if you have access to the subsystem. Note that you can [balance between multiple services on the same device](https://serverfault.com/questions/242679/how-to-run-multiple-nginx-instances-on-different-port) using this method too!